# Magento 2 CE, 2.2.4. Does it matter if I keep getting error: main.CRITICAL: Too late for the schedule {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0):

Tags: magento

I see we have loads of the same message on `/var/log/exception.log`

Is this something we need to resolve?
If yes, please can anyone advise? (I am a newbie so nothing too technical please:))

> [2018-11-04 09:13:03] main.CRITICAL: Too late for the schedule {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Too late for the schedule at /home/TED/public_html/vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php:273)"} []

Comment: From what I understand: The "Too late for the schedule" error message in the Exception.log occurs when the scheduler detects a job that was supposed to run in the past (before a given threshold) but hasn't been started yet. In this case it's going to be skipped with this message.
It seems that those errors have occurred because the crons are not configured to run correctly. I need to ensure cron is called at least every 5 mins on cpanel and backend Magento is configured correctly to generate the schedule correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What interval do you run the default cronjobs on? DevDocs recommends 1min interval for crontab https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Comment: Hi, on cPanel they are set to every 5 mins and Index is set to 15 mins: */5 * * * * /public_html/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /public_html/var/log/magento.cron.log
*/5 * * * * /public_html/update/cron.php >> public_html/var/log/update.cron.log
*/5 * * * * /public_html/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /public_html/var/log/setup.cron.log
*/15 * * * * /public_html/bin/magento indexer:reindex